# Why does my command works in the CLI but not with a cron job?

Tags: php, macos, command-line, terminal, cron

I have the following command that works on the terminal as is:

```
php ~/Sites/meetmyfriends-back/index.php tools reset_avail
```

I am trying to do a cron job but it’s not working.

```
0 6 * * * php ~/Sites/meetmyfriends-back/index.php tools reset_avail
```

I want it every day at 6 am.

Why is it not working?

I would alsolike to storethe logs in a file with `>> ~/MyFile` but that didn’t work as well. Neither the `MAILTO:my@email.com`.

Please advise. I am on Mac OS X 10.10.

EDIT: after several trials, here is where I am right now:

```
0 6 * * * /usr/bin/php /Users/YohannM/Sites/meetmyfriends-back/index.php tools reset_avail >> /Users/YohannM/Sites/meetmyfriends-back/resetA.log
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pretty confident the problem is the relative `~/` path:

```
0 6 * * * php ~/Sites/meetmyfriends-back/index.php tools reset_avail
```

You should set the full path to the script. Something like this; of course change `/Users/MilesM` to your actual path:

```
0 6 * * * php /Users/MilesM/Sites/meetmyfriends-back/index.php tools reset_avail
```

The issue is that when you run a command via a cron job, it will not be loading all of the bash settings & paths that you get when you login. So in the terminal, `~/` makes sense, but for a cron job `/Users/MilesM/` is the way to go.

You also ask:

> I would alsolike to storethe logs in a file with `>> ~/MyFile` but
>   that didn’t work as well. Neither the `MAILTO:my@email.com`.

For `>> ~/MyFile` the solution is the same. You must set the full path like this:

```
>> /Users/MilesM//MyFile
```

But unclear about `MAILTO:my@email.com`. That is an HTML tag. Do you mean you are attempting to mail via the PHP script? Unsure about that part of it.

Also, of you need to specify the full PHP path you can do this. First, figure out what the full PHP path is by using `which` like this:

```
which php
```

On my Mac OS X setup it returns:

```
/usr/bin/php
```

So the full command would be:

```
0 6 * * * /usr/bin/php /Users/MilesM/Sites/meetmyfriends-back/index.php tools reset_avail
```

And that should work.

Comment: Might even need the full path to the `php` executable, depending on the `$PATH` cron runs with:  `/usr/bin/php /Users/Miles/Sites..../index.php tools reset_avail`

Comment: I will let you know asap if this is necessary or not.

Comment: Unfortunately, `0 6 * * * php /Users/MilesM/Sites/meetmyfriends-back/index.php tools reset_avail` doesn't work.
I'm gonna try what Michael B. suggested.